# How can I build a app apk with jQuery Mobile getting its data from website?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm building a blog type app with jQuery Mobile once I'm done I want to upload online under a domain mobile website but i want users to be able to download as a app on the app stores and i want to write a everyday blog on the site and they get the latest feed on the app. I know its possible just don't know how? Im only using html, js, and css

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). PhoneGap is same as, and built upon, Cordova with some Adobe tools built in. Although, there can be some architectural differences that you will have to keep in mind while developing applications for mobiles e.g. offline capabilities, speed of navigation between pages etc.